# Call function in another .php file (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have a **sample.php** file. is there a function here that i want to pass in another **sample.js** file

for example in sample.php file i have this function

```
function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId) {

 gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
  'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
  'start-date': '7daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'yesterday',
  'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
  'dimensions' : 'ga:date'
 })
 .then(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
 })
 .then(null, function(err) {
  // Log any errors.
  console.log(err);
 });
}
```

how do i call this in my sample.js file? or how do i call the response of this function? Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `php` runs on the server while `js` runs in the browser or as a client (in this case). It means that they can't be call directly.

But you can use `AJAX`(in js) to call php.

Example:

```
$.get('sample.php',your_args, function(call_result){
    console.log(call_result);
});
```

By the way, that is **not** a php code but a js code!

Comment: @AyDee your code in php file is not a valid php code. If it is you can use this method. In your current case you can use the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in script tags and place it right before the tag that closes the  **body**.

```
<script>
function queryCoreReportingApi(profileId) {

 gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
  'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
  'start-date': '7daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'yesterday',
  'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
  'dimensions' : 'ga:date'
 })
 .then(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
 })
 .then(null, function(err) {
  // Log any errors.
  console.log(err);
 });
}</script>
</body>
```